# How does Apple's AirTunes actually work?

Tags: wireless-networking, itunes

I am trying to understand how AirTunes actually works. It somehow sends my songs to a wireless device via iTunes and only iTunes. Shouldn't this also be possible via a different program?

It can't be so complicated, but I am trying to understand why it is possible with iTunes.

Comment: Note that because there can be some buffering and latency, it's not appropriate for interactive audio like games, live two-way audio chat, and system UI sounds. That's why it's not provided as a generic system audio output devices.

Answer (score 1):

It works like [this](http://git.zx2c4.com/Airtunes2/about/).

Comment: -1: Link-only answers are bad.

Comment: Questions that can be answered by Google are bad.

Answer (score 0):

It's a streaming audio protocol that Apple has implemented for a variety of its hardware and software.

There's nothing "special" about iTunes except that that just happens to be where Apple has implemented it.

Rogue Amoeba has a piece of software called [Airfoil](http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/) that implements this functionality and expands upon it outside of iTunes.